# Unable to compile i386 compatible ffmpeg dylibs on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, x86, osx-lion, 32bit-64bit

I'm running 64-bit Lion but I need to compile a 32-bit version of ffmpeg because another library I'm using is only available as 32-bit. I've tried a number of different configurations but they're all giving me errors. Here's what I've tried:

> ./configure --disable-static --enable-shared --disable-outdev=sdl --disable-bzlib --disable-libfreetype --disable-libopenjpeg --enable-zlib --enable-runtime-cpudetect --arch=i386 --extra-cflags="-arch i386" --extra-ldflags="-arch i386" --target-os=darwin --enable-cross-compile
>
> ./configure --disable-static --enable-shared --disable-outdev=sdl --disable-bzlib --disable-libfreetype --disable-libopenjpeg --enable-zlib --enable-runtime-cpudetect --arch=i386 --extra-cflags="-arch i386" --extra-ldflags="-arch i386"
>
> ./configure --disable-static --enable-shared --disable-outdev=sdl --disable-bzlib --disable-libfreetype --disable-libopenjpeg --enable-zlib --enable-runtime-cpudetect --arch=x86_32

I either get a "ran out of registers during register allocation" error during make or gcc complains that cross-compile is not active.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to get this working on ffmpeg build 08d2cee4 by using clang instead of gcc. So here was configure line that worked:

```
./configure --disable-static --enable-shared --disable-outdev=sdl --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-bzlib --disable-libfreetype --disable-libopenjpeg --enable-zlib --cc="clang -m32"
```

Thanks to Carl on libav-user!

Here was my thread in case it helps anyone: http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2011-December/001013.html

Answer (score 1):

You might try using the -m32 flag which tells gcc to compile for 32-bit only.

Comment: no luck when adding this to `extra-cflags` and `extra-ldflags` :-(. same error about running out of registers.

Comment: I also followed the advice on http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/mplayer-users/2011-August/083095.html to add -cc="gcc -m32" but got same result

Comment: Oops, sorry I skipped over what you wrote about the registers error.  That is probably unrelated to the 32 bit flag, and you'll need to figure that one out first.

Comment: well I think it's somewhat related because I can compile just fine if I leave things on 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess - was it building: `libavcodec/h264_cabac.o`?

Try adding `-fomit-frame-pointer`. IIRC, there's some gcc inline assembly that can't get hold of enough registers. This option frees up `%ebp` for use as a general purpose register.

Comment: that's right, it's always on `libavcodec/h264_cabac.o`. I tried adding `-fomit-frame-pointer` to `extra-cflags` and `extra-ldflags` but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

i resolve the error "ran out of registers during register allocation" with --disable-asm

maybe you could try it.